# Copying File to Backup File Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to do the following which I've already started:

- Prompt user to enter a folder and see if it is readable
- If file is not readable it needs to display a message and end
- Then copy that folder into a backup folder
- Read each line of the backup folder and display each line

Here's what I have but I keep getting a missing destination operand error.

`echo -n "Please enter a file name:"
read file
if [ -r "$file" ]
then
echo [ $file ] >> /home/shawn/backupfile.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < "$file"
else
echo "File is not readable or does not exist"
fi`

Answer (score 0):

```
cp $file >> backupfile.txt
```

Should be:

```
cp "$file" backupfile.txt
```

`>>` is used to *append output*, which is not what you need to do.

Other things:

- Quote your variables: Use `"$file"`. What will happen if user enters `File Name With Spaces`?
- `file=$file` is a tautology. And unnecessary.

Comment: How do I display all the lines in the backup file?

Comment: @DSH72 http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Where does the line display go in the script? Sorry very green with shell scripting

Comment: @DSH72 After the  `cp` command? You're supposed to read the backup file, right?

Comment: Yes that's part of the requirments

Comment: Yes, I am suppose to read all lines from the `backupfile.txt` and display them when the script is ran

Comment: @DSH72 so use the `while` loop given in the link, and add it after the `cp` command.

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line;` error: 0: is directory........this is what I got when I ran it after inserting the loop in the link

Comment: @DSH72 update your question with what the script looks like now.

Comment: I've updated the script I couldn't get the cp command to work I kept getting errors...This seems to be able to copy the file to the backup folder but I can't do much past that.